# Crop image into square and then to circle using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make a circle out of images with different sizes and different shapes (some rectangle, some sqaure, some portrait, some landscape).

When I'm using: `clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);` or `border-radius: 50%;`, it turns the image into a perfect circle, **only** if the image is square:

[image]

Is there a way to crop an image into a square and then use one of these methods to make it a perfect circle:

1. Using pure CSS **withou using** `background-image` (most images are given the background image from server side),
2. Keeping a 50% ratio - without losing aspect ratio - (both if `border-radius` or `clip-path`)(Images size may vary).

Here's a code snippet to show a square image and a rectangle image:

```css
.clipped {
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
}
```

```html
Square<br>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/d5byNNR.jpg' width="100" class='clipped' /><br><br>
Rectangle<br>
<img src='http://i.imgur.com/22W12EQ.jpg' width="100" class='clipped' />
```

Comment: BTW this is a picture of my daughter so copyrights are mine! :)

Comment: You said *Is there a way to turn an image into a square*. Are you saying you are okay to resize a rectangular image into a square and losing the aspect ratio of the image?

Comment: @FrankFajardo Not losing the aspect ratio - cropping it into a square.

Comment: Using just `clip-path: circle();` seems to work. It clips the image to a circle and uses the smaller side as the circumference. But it obviously is keeping only the central part of the image.

Comment: @FrankFajardo That's write - but when I use `circle(50% at 50% 50%);` with a rectangle, you can see the result, it's not a circle. Since I cannot know the size of my images, I have to keep it with `%` units.

Comment: I mean `circle()` without the parameters. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59a4b5mo/1/).

Comment: @FrankFajardo Groovy. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want a pure CSS solution? I mean, with Javascript this could be a whole lot easier. Pure CSS seems to be to limited to get a perfect result in all cases. Especially since `clip-path` isn't fully supported yet.

Comment: @icecub Can you please explain how?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't my downvote. I was wondering the same thing. Anyway, with Javascript you could dynamicly get the dimensions of each image and crop them exactly where you want instead of having to rely on the borders of the image (that's what `clip-path` does if no parameters are given).

Comment: And because the cropping is done with Javascript, it'll work in all browsers. After that it's a simple matter of using `border-radius: 50%` :)

Comment: @icecub Care to post this as an answer with a running example? I'm very curious to see it. And again, thanks.

Comment: Of course, I'll see what I can come up with

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`circle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#circle()) but without the parameters:

```
.clipped {
   clip-path: circle();
}
```

It appears to use the smaller side of your image as the circle's circumference.

Working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/59a4b5mo/1/).

It works on Chrome and FireFox. IE and Edge still does not support `clip-path`

Comment: Just to add a note that [`clip-path` at this stage is considered *experimental technology* by MDN; so it may change in the future](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to do it for IE via CSS?

Comment: Not without JS.

Answer (score 2):

That's an another way to do it using *pure CSS*:

**HTML**

```
<div class="circular--portrait">
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/22W12EQ.jpg'/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circular--portrait {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circular--portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

[Code Snippet (with portrait and landscape examples)](https://jsfiddle.net/6aw0892g/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you see, int the snippet you provided, that the image lost ratio? It's distorted.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Voted up for the suggestion.

Comment: Why this was added?
```margin-top: -30px;```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, took me a moment but this is what I came up with:

```js
function ScaleImage(srcwidth, srcheight, targetwidth, targetheight, fLetterBox, xOffSet, yOffSet) {

 var result = { width: 0, height: 0, fScaleToTargetWidth: true };

 if ((srcwidth <= 0) || (srcheight <= 0) || (targetwidth <= 0) || (targetheight <= 0)) {
  return result;
 }

 // scale to the target width
 var scaleX1 = targetwidth;
 var scaleY1 = (srcheight * targetwidth) / srcwidth;

 // scale to the target height
 var scaleX2 = (srcwidth * targetheight) / srcheight;
 var scaleY2 = targetheight;

 // now figure out which one we should use
 var fScaleOnWidth = (scaleX2 > targetwidth);
 if (fScaleOnWidth) {
  fScaleOnWidth = fLetterBox;
 }
 else {
    fScaleOnWidth = !fLetterBox;
 }

 if (fScaleOnWidth) {
  result.width = Math.floor(scaleX1);
  result.height = Math.floor(scaleY1);
  result.fScaleToTargetWidth = true;
 }
 else {
  result.width = Math.floor(scaleX2);
  result.height = Math.floor(scaleY2);
  result.fScaleToTargetWidth = false;
 }
 //result.targetleft = Math.floor((targetwidth - result.width) / 2);
 //result.targettop = Math.floor((targetheight - result.height) / 2);

 result.targetleft = Math.floor((targetwidth - result.width) / 2 - xOffSet);
 result.targettop = Math.floor((targetheight - result.height) / 2 - yOffSet);

 return result;
}

function OnImageLoad(evt, xOffSet = 0, yOffSet = 0) {

 var img = evt.currentTarget;

 // what's the size of this image and it's parent
 var w = $(img).width();
 var h = $(img).height();
 var tw = $(img).parent().width();
 var th = $(img).parent().height();

 // compute the new size and offsets
 var result = ScaleImage(w, h, tw, th, false, xOffSet, yOffSet);

 // adjust the image coordinates and size
 img.width = result.width;
 img.height = result.height;
 $(img).css("left", result.targetleft);
 $(img).css("top", result.targettop);
}
```

```css
.result {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: thick solid #666666;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
No offset:
<div class='result'>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/22W12EQ.jpg" style="position: absolute;" onload="OnImageLoad(event, 0, 0);"/>
</div>
Y offset:
<div class='result'>
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/22W12EQ.jpg" style="position: absolute;" onload="OnImageLoad(event, 0, 30);"/>
</div>
```

I took most of the work from this resource: https://selbie.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/scale-crop-and-center-an-image-with-correct-aspect-ratio-in-html-and-javascript/ and I've adepted it to allow the use of Offsets so you can crop any image at the position you want.

**How it works**
You create a div of any size you want. It can be square, but if you want an egg-like result, that works as well (lol). Then insert the image of any unknown size inside it.

Change `onload="OnImageLoad(event, 0, 30);` with the offsets you want. Positive offsets for moving the image left or down, negative for up or right.

Note: I did use jQuery for this.

Comment: Beautiful post. I will implement it and see how it goes against Frank Fajardo's suggestion. +1 vote anyway.

Comment: @KobyDouek Just happy to give you an alternative that should work in all browsers :)

Comment: @KobyDouek Ye as I said at the end: I've used jQuery with this. Just add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your html (before the javascript above) and it should work perfectly fine :)

Comment: No, I know, but for a second there your snippet here at SO had errors, I guess you edited it and then fixed it. All is good now. thanks.

Comment: @KobyDouek Hmm, I didn't fix anything. Perhaps a hickup in SO? Anyway, glad it's working out now